# Make a .NET 4 Task stop and resume

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

Hi all: is there a way I can stop a Task and wake it up later? 
I know there is WaitOrTimerCallback in ThreadPool class, but cannot find a corresponding stuff for Task.

Comment: You will have to implement that yourself using your favorite thread management approach (reset events, semaphores, w/e)

Comment: You can't find any because here isn't one. `Task`s don't have that functionality. You'd have to use lower level APIs.

Comment: Hi, can you provide some links about it?

Comment: Why not do a Task.Delay on a while loop? Until the condition is the while is not satisfied, do a Task.Delay

Comment: @Ronald: never knew Delay(), will try it out. Thanks.

Comment: @Ricky I'll be posting an answer then so you can close this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and do a while loop with a flag outside the method. You can use the Task.Delay method to prevent execution continuation.

More details on Task Delay: [Task Delay - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay(v=vs.110).aspx)